# SQL query to find maximum tax brackets

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database table of tax brackets in a variety of locations with the fields: `location`, `tax_bracket`, and `tax_rate`.

I need to create a query that will return a list of countries, with their highest tax rate, that have at least one tax bracket with a tax rate over X.

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to post your table schema for the relevant tables, or at least a representative example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample to get you started, without knowing your schema:

```
Select
  LocationName,
  MaxTaxRate
FROM
  (select
    Max(tax_rate) as MaxTaxRate,
    LocationName
  from
    MyLocations
  group by
    LocationName
  ) as MaxTable
```

You will have to join up with other information, but this is as far as I can go efficiently without more schema info.

Answer (score 0):

select location, max(tax_rate) from tax_brackets where tax_rate > x group by location

the tax_rate > x should filter all tax_rates lower x, which means if the location has no tax_rates over x, they do not have at least one rate over x, which means they won't appear in the group by.

The group by should organize by location.
The select does location and max of those per location.

Comment: This is perfect, I didn't know about the max() function.